# laravel jwt change token expired time

Tags: laravel, jwt, token

I'm using tymondesigns/jwt-auth to generate a token
It works fine
The problem is that I need to change the token validate time to 1 minute to make some tests

```
I've changed the file jwt.php:
```

'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 1), and tried too:
'ttl' => 1,

It doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I tried to clean the cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

It doesn't work. I figure out that if I have to clean the cache config:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Now, it works fine